# Setting the default guard on a route group

Tags: php, laravel

I have set up an API token for my users which they can optionally provide when accessing API routes for additional data to be returned.

This is my *auth.php* configuration:

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',      
],    
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'eloquent',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'eloquent',
    ],
],
```

I have various (shared) places in my code which use checks like `$request->user()` without providing the guard. The problem is that this always uses the default guard.

However if I set one of the API routes as to use middleware `auth:api` then it uses the api guard by default as I'd expect. I can't really set that up though because as I mentioned, authentication is optional and using the auth middleware makes it mandatory.

I'm wondering if there's a way to set all API routes such that their default guard is the API guard.

Comment: for reference, there is also https://mattallan.me/posts/setting-the-guard-per-route-in-laravel/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After some fiddling about I think I've found what I think is a sensible solution:

I've created the following middleware:

```
class GuardSwitcher {
    public function handle($request, \Closure $next, $defaultGuard = null) {
        if (in_array($defaultGuard, array_keys(config("auth.guards")))) {
           config(["auth.defaults.guard" => $defaultGuard]);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

I then added this as a route middleware:

```
 protected $routeMiddleware = [ 
          // ... more
          'guardswitcher' => GuardSwitcher::class
 ];
```

I then added this middleware in my api middleware stack in `Kernel.php` i.e.:

```
'api' => [
     'guardswitcher:api',
     // ... more
 ],
```

After this process this is what the `Kernel.php` would look like:

```
class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    protected $middleware = [
       //These are the global framework middleware which were not changed
    ];

    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
           //Web middleware, no changes here
        ],

        'api' => [
            'guardswitch:api',
            // Other group middleware
        ]
    ];

    protected $routeMiddleware = [ 
        // Other middleware go here   
        'guardswitch' => DefaultGuardSwitch::class, // This is what's added
    ];
}
```

Comment: can you please clear this answer little bit You said `I then added this as a route middleware` where this should go exactly and then you said `stack in Kernel.php` you mean here `'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],` btw I am using `Laravel 5.4`

Comment: @YousefAltaf I've added a skeleton outline of my `Kernel.php` which has only the changed parts. I didn't remove anything that was already in my Kernel.php.

Answer (score 14):

For me the easiest was to add to the Api\Controller (The one that extends all your classes), the following line:

```
public function __construct()
{
    // We set the guard api as default driver
    auth()->setDefaultDriver('api');
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. I think this is the best solution. Easy and clean

Comment: `Auth::setDefaultDriver('api')` can work too if you are using ide helper.

Answer (score 6):

I believe this achieves the same results.

**Kernel**

```
        //...
        'api' => [
        //...
        GuardSwitcher::class
    ],
```

**Guard Switcher Middleware**

```
class GuardSwitcher
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (auth()->getDefaultDriver() == 'web') {

            auth()->setDefaultDriver('api');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

The default driver will now be set for all incoming request from either the api routes file or from within an api group.

Answer (score -1):

If I've understood correctly, you could use [Route-Groups](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-groups) for this.

All routes in a route group will, in this example, have to go through the auth middleware.

```
    Route::group( [ 'middleware' => 'auth' ], function(){
        Route::get('/page',  'Controller@function');
    } );
```

Comment: This will not work for me because it will force all routes in the group to only work if a user is authenticated. What I want is for all routes in that group to check if a user is authenticated on the "API" guard by default, but currently they use the "web" guard by default.