# Laravel auth middleware

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I have a controller and in my controller I have an index function that returns data back to the user.

The user can filter the query that they want the index function to return.

I noticed that only routes with the `auth:api` middleware would return a user object when I tried calling `Auth::user()`.

Now my function returns all events in my database.  A user can filter the results like this `?filter=my` to return a list of events they created.  The issue here is the user has to be logged in before they can see events they created.

My problem is if I wrap this route with `auth:api` then guest users will not be able to use it.  However if I don't then that particular filter that requires a user to be logged in will always return empty.

This is my controller:

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $categoryId = $request->get("category_id");
        $userId = Auth::check() ? Auth::user()->id : 0;
        $filter = $request->get("filter");
        $keyword = $request->get("keyword");

        $events = Event::with(["category", "organisers", "banners", "schedules.ticketTypes", "schedules.venue", "schedules.programme"])
            ->when(!empty($categoryId), function ($query) use ($categoryId) {
                return $query->where("category_id", $categoryId);
            })
            ->whereNull("suspended_at")
            ->when($filter == "popular", function ($query) use ($categoryId) {
                return $query->orderBy("views", "DESC")
                    ->limit(15);
            })
            ->when($filter == "upcoming", function ($query) {
                return $query->whereHas("schedules", function ($query) {
                    $query->where("date", ">=", Carbon::now())
                        ->where("date", "<", Carbon::now()->addDays(14))
                        ->limit(15);
                });
            })
            /* This part requires the auth:api middleware since I will be querying based on the user's id which I will get from the auth token passed in thee header.*/
            ->when($filter == "my", function ($query) use ($userId) {
                return $query->whereHas("organisers", function ($query) use ($userId) {
                    $query->where("id", $userId)
                        ->limit(15);
                });
            })
            ->when($filter == "search" && !empty($keyword), function ($query) use ($keyword) {
                return $query->where("slug", "LIKE", "%" . $keyword . "%");
            })
            ->get();

        return EventResource::collection($events);
    }
```

This is my **Kernel.php:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'acl' => \Kodeine\Acl\Middleware\HasPermission::class
    ];
}
```

In summary my index function does not require user to be logged in to access it. However when you pass the filter `?filter=my` to the url then user is required to be logged in for data to be returned since the function will return results based on the user's id.

**Edit:**
previously in situations like this I would use *jwt.check* middleware when I was using tymon/jwt-auth package. However there doesn't seem to be a passport equivalent of that.

Comment: The easiest way to deal with this would be to not show the `my` filter option to guest users?

Comment: What is it that you wanna achieve actually, I don't think I understand that part correctly

Comment: The index function does not require user to be logged in to access it.  However when you pass the filter ```?fitler=my``` then user is required to be logged in.

Comment: I think this relates to a question I had posted in the past https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49071605/setting-the-default-guard-on-a-route-group

Comment: @Joe that's not exactly the problem, when I don't wrap the route in auth:api middleware then my Auth::user() always returns null.

Comment: Can you add your middleware kernel code to the question please?

Comment: Done. Have edited my post.

Comment: So basically what you are saying is that in order to return someones events, that person needs to be logged in so you know for who you are returning it, but you also want this to work with users which are not logged in? I still don't understand what is your exact issue here

Answer (score 0):

Update the filter `my` as follows:

```
->when($filter == "my" && $userId != 0, function ($query) use ($userId) {
    ...
})
```

Then it will be ignored when `$userId` is 0.

Comment: the problem is my route is not wrapped in auth::api so I can't get the logged in user id.

Comment: How are you logging in your users?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that i understand it correctly but if I did what about:

```
$userId = Auth::guard('api')->check() ? Auth::guard('api')->user()->id : null; 


->when($filter == "my" && $userId, function ($query) use ($userId) {
      return $query->whereHas("organisers", function ($query) use ($userId) {
            $query->where("id", $userId)->limit(15);
      });
 })
```

Comment: did you try the Auth::guard('api')? and the $filter == "my" && $userId?